# react-native-firebase: onNotificationOpenedApp and getInitialNotification not working on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I'm using Cloud Messaging from react-native-firebase 7.0.1.

I do not want to store iOS device tokens in firebase, so I'm using `getAPNSToken()` method and then storing it on my backend.

I'm able to send notification on a device and after pressing it, the application opens.

But when I'm trying to get message from `getInitialNotification()` or `onNotificationOpenedApp()` it always returns `null`/`undefined`.

It works every time on Android.

**PushHandler.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

export default class PushHandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.messageApp = messaging();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.messageApp.onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) { // <- always null on iOS
        // handle notification
      }
    });

    this.messageApp.getInitialNotification().then(initialMessage => {
      if (initialMessage) { // <- always undefined on iOS
        // handle notification
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and working through it now. Will let you know if I figure it out. Have you made progress here?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. @LouieAnderson- Can you please share details on how you have solved this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just realized that according to the docs, these functions only work when sending and receiving notifications via FCM, which is why you aren't seeing these work when sending them manually through APNS.

This package will allow for leverage getInitialNotification and the other function: https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios

Answer (score 3):

It used to work before. I mean, for the RNFirebase 5.x.x versions.
For some reason, the maintainers of the library decided to only send those events up to the JS layer when it's a Firebase Cloud Message coming through.

Here is the IF statement:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/packages/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessaging%2BUNUserNotificationCenter.m#L89

[image]

I removed the IF statement it seems to be working as before.
But yeah, that's the new behavior of the RN-Firebase library.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a lot for this important hint!