# messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp and messaging().getInitialNotification() not working in React native IOS app & working in Android

Tags: ios, reactjs, notifications, react-native-firebase

as Mentioned in subject

messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp and messaging().getInitialNotification() are not working in React native IOS app but its working in Android

I have dependancy which uses Flipper and I am aware that Firebase needs UseFrameworks and they don't work with each other

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!


flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'myApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  flags = get_default_flags()
     pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseSessions', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true
     
     $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true 
     use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'HeyGroopAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

  pre_install do |installer|
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.eql?('RNCallKeep')
    def pod.build_type
    Pod::BuildType.static_library
    end
    end
    end
    end

end
 

target 'ShareMenu' do
    use_react_native!
  
    pod 'RNShareMenu', :path => '../node_modules/rn-rnf-share-menu'
    # Manually link packages here to keep your extension bundle size minimal
    use_react_native!(
       :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
      )
  end
```

this is how my pod file looks

I am trying to get firebase notification on open listeners work

I have also tried removing flipper dependancy and enable user frameworks :static and not luck same issue

any inputs would be appreciable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148720/react-native-firebase-onnotificationopenedapp-and-getinitialnotification-not-wo
this issue looks similar but not of the answers are helpful

Comment: function getInitialNotification invoked and getting null
function  onNotificationOpenedApp not invoked

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the latest version of Notifee react native
@notifee/react-native@6.0.0 - used this version and The issue is been handled

and the code started working as expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same problem. My issue was I have used notifee library to handle local notifications. According to their documentation *onNotificationOpenedApp* and *getInitialNotification* from RNFB Messaging will no longer trigger and notifee will handle the event. I was able to fix this by,

1. **Replacing onNotificationOpenedApp with notifee.onForegrandEvent**
2. **Replacing getInitialNotification with notifee.onForegrandEvent**

You can also refer this article. https://atsss.medium.com/replace-all-default-fcm-notifications-with-notifee-on-ios-751cb38f6dab

Happy coding!